# Guardar Circular Structure con File System

Tags: javascript, json, scraping

Tengo una aplicación que hace Web Scrapping a un sitio, cuando obtengo la data de este sitio la guardo en una variable para posteriormente crear un archivo con File System y guardar la información, el problema es que es me da el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

CODIGO

```js
const express = require('express')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs')
const router = express.Router()
let globalPage

async function startApp() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://www.rappi.com.co/')
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        isMobile: false
    })
    await page.click('#header > div > div.header-content-right.not-logged > div.header-user-dropdown.ng-star-inserted > app-user-drop-down > div > button', {
        button: 'left'
    })
    globalPage = page
}

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await startApp()
    fs.writeFile('puppeteerPage.txt', globalPage, (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
    console.log('browser started')
    res.render('Home')
})

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/home/phoneNumber')
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Una estructura circular es un objeto que hace referencia a si mismo por lo que hacer un JSON.stringify() de dicho objeto te retornaría el error que comentas por eso al intentar guardarlo en un archivo te marca dicho error, lo que se tiene que hacer es convertir dicho objeto a texto que es la información que deseas. Si pudieras agregar que módulo y como es tu función del elemento para hacer el scrapping sería de gran apoyo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, ya agregue el código, e intente guardándolo como texto pero el error aun persiste(lo guarda como [object, object]

Comment: significa que se esta guardando bien, `[Object, object]` es lo que imprime cuando intentas usar algo que no sea la consola para imprimir un objeto. por ejemplo un `alert` o un `document.write`.

Comment: Esta guardando la información pero no permite manipularla, debería que mostrar el archivo con el objeto en si.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que deseas guardar? ¿Es todo el contenido de la página? o algún texto en especifico?

Comment: En si quiero guardar el contenido de la pagina que me genera puppeteer, para de esta manera poder modular mi aplicación y poder manipular el mismo sitio web desde otros archivos, sin tener que abrir otro navegador.